# Why does IE show a horizontal scrollbar when wrapper div is defined with width 100%?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a fluid design for an intranet. However, the style underneath always makes IE always show a horizontal scrollbar. If I change the `#wrapper` div width to, for instance, 600px, then the scrollbar disappears. So that is where the problem is.

However, my question then is: **why** does a width of 100% cause the horizontal scrollbar? And how do I solve it?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">

<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <style>
      * { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
      body { background: #ccc; margin: 10px; }
      #wrapper { width: 100%; background: #fff; min-height: 100%; }
      #header  { height: 80px; border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc; }
      #faux    { height: 100%; }
      #menu    { float: left; width: 180px; }
      #content { float: right; width: 100px; }

      #header img { float: left; }
      #header h2 { margin-top: 25px; float: right; }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="wrapper">
      <div id="header"><img src="theme/logo.gif"><h2>Pagetitle</h2></div>
      <div id="faux">
        <div id="menu"><?php echo $menu; ?></div>
        <div id="content"><?php echo $content; ?></div>
      </div>
    </div>    
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi, can you please tell the IE version you use?

Comment: Works for me on IE8 upwards. Why aren't you making it in HTML5? Many UI frameworks are available with a lot of reusable examples for the same.

Comment: set X-UA-Compatible header to IE=edge otherwise it may render as IE7. your code was tested on IE8 and above and it works. Please be aware that IE7 and older uses different box model as you may already know, border and padding is included as element width.

Comment: I am using IE 10. Inserting `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">` doesn't work for me. Zoom is at 100%

Comment: In IE10 it works withour a problem. Maybe you have set the ZOOM mode in IE to more than 100%, and that can cause the layout to break. Can you check this?

Comment: Or another thing, which IE can have a problem with - that you set a margin for the BODY tag, and as the body tag does not have a width set - You set the DIV inside to 100%, it will cause the body div to be 100%(=window width) + 10px margin around, so it is more than "100%" and will cause the scrollbar to appear.

Comment: @Asped I just checked. This does not cause the issue. Thanks though for your input. I don't understand why nobody else is having issues with this code. I'm quite sure I did not alter any of IE's settings since it is a clean install...

Comment: What program do you use to code with? I had this same problem once because of [HTML BOM](http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-byte-order-mark)

Comment: @gelleby http://sourceforge.net/projects/notepad2/ - very simple so I don't think this is where the problem is. Thanks for all the input, it is really appreciated!

Comment: Are you sure, did you check your settings in notepad2, are you coding in UTF-8?

Answer (score 1):

This is weird. I didn't think it mattered, so I did not paste all of the css. In reality I have:

```
#header h2 { margin-top: 25px; float: right; font-style: italic; }
```

The issue of the horizontal scrollbar is caused by `font-style: italic`. Once deleted, everything worked fine. Include it, and the page breaks. Does anybody know why?